# How can I add keywords to common editors？

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm learning data structure. I tried coding to assist my learning. Sometimes I need to highlight some keywords in pseudo code ("SeqList","SqList","ElemType") as the color of the preset keywords ("int").

I do know I can add keywords in vim, for example, `: syn keyword type seqlist`, could dye the word "seqlist" as "int". But I wonder if mainstream editors (vscode, clion, Xcode, sublime) can achieve this?

Comment: search in the Extension Marketplace for `highlight`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used VIM for some days to highlight the keywords defined by myself, using `syntax keyword` and `syntax match`